# Flutter - Enable/Disable button when length is greater or less than 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for the button to be enabled or disabled, while I'm writing in the textField. If the length of the text is greater than 0, I need the button to be enabled.

```
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  static var nameProduct;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  return Dialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
    child: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  controller: myController,
                  onChanged: (String text) {
                    nameProduct = text;
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (nameProduct.isNotEmpty)
                                            ? () => {
                                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                                      .pop(false),
                                                  myMethod()
                                                }
                                            : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ));
```

With the code I publish here, it's not working for me.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The build method is not being called again to perform the redraw.

You can use the `setState(() {});` like this:

```
onChanged: (String text) {
   setState(() {
      nameProduct = text;
   });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that the widget is only built once. Therefore, subsequent changes to your textfield do not tell Flutter to rebuild the widget.